# How to create a Xamarin.Forms Windows phone 8.1 project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2017

I cannot find a Visual Studio 2017 project for making Xamarin.Forms Windows 8.1 apps. How do I install it?

Comment: I think you need the VS2013/2015 to create 8.1 apps. 2017 removed the development support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8.1 Silverlight and RT are all deprecated. I would suggest doing a UWP app and targeting Windows 10 instead.

However, if you do want to do a Windows 8.1 project. Make sure you download the [Windows 8.1 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive), then create a new Xamarin.Forms project. Then you will have to add a new Windows 8.1 project afterwards, and manually add the Xamarin.Forms Init code, in the project.

You can have a look at [XArch](https://github.com/adamped/xarch-starter) for an example.

But once again, I strongly recommend against, creating a Windows 8.1 project, and you should do UWP instead.

Comment: I have looked but I can't find a current adoption rate for Windows 10 Mobile.